# Apache SSI not working

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, ssi

I am running an Apache (version 2.2.22) web server on an Ubuntu 12.04 server. SSI is not working. The classic `<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->` in an *index.shtml* page is not interpreted. In */etc/apache2/httpd.conf* I have put:

```
Options +Includes 
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

and in */etc/apache2/sites-available/default* :

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +ExecCGI +Includes
            AllowOverride All
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
         DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
```

moreover, the *error.log* gives me:

```
[Wed May 07 13:51:23 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 07 13:51:26 2014] [error] an unknown filter was not added: includes
[Wed May 07 13:51:27 2014] [error] an unknown filter was not added: includes
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: This question may belong on Ask Ubuntu? Either way, I think it definitely is helpful, though I needed a bit more understanding to get my Apache SSI working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200522/apache-not-processing-basic-ssi

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the problem: I simply had to load the `include` module. In practice I only had to `a2enmod include` and it fixed the problem.

Sorry for the stupid question. I leave it for those who could spend a whole day looking for such an evident thing, like me...

Comment: Note you also need mod_perl (`perl.load`), which is also not enabled by default. `include.load` alone isn't enough.

Comment: Now it seems I also need `AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html`. I'm pretty sure I didn't need this in 2016 on my old version.